# Transfer data to HBASE using Pig

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-pig

I have pseudo distributed mode.. Versions are as follows...

```
 kandabap@prakashl:~$ hadoop version
    Hadoop 1.2.0

    kandabap@prakashl:~$ pig version
    Apache Pig version 0.12.0 (r1529718) compiled Oct 07 2013, 12:20:14
    kandabap@prakashl:~$ hbase version
    HBase 0.90.1-cdh3u0
```

I am trying to transfer data into HBASE using PIG script as follows...

```
PIG_CLASSPATH=/usr/lib/hbase/hbase-0.94.8/hbase-0.94.8.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/hbase-0.94.8/lib/zookeeper-3.4.5.jar /usr/lib/pig/pig-0.12.0/bin/pig /home/kandabap/Documents/H/HBASE/scripts.pig
```

But there seems to be some errors as,

```
 Failed Jobs:
    JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs
    job_201405201031_0005   raw_data    MAP_ONLY    Message: Job failed! Error - JobCleanup Task Failure, Task: task_201405201031_0005_m_000001 hbase://sample_names,

    Input(s):
    Failed to read data from "/input.csv"

    Output(s):
    Failed to produce result in "hbase://sample_names"

    Counters:
    Total records written : 0
    Total bytes written : 0
    Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
    Total bags proactively spilled: 0
    Total records proactively spilled: 0

    Job DAG:
    job_201405201031_0005


    2014-05-20 11:14:59,604 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Failed!
    2014-05-20 11:14:59,608 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser - ERROR 2244: Job failed, hadoop does not return any error message
    Details at logfile: /usr/lib/hbase/hbase-0.94.8/pig_1400548430579.log
```

Comment: Could paste the error log and an example of your script?

Comment: I have attached the screen log already in my question... Additional info are ,

Comment: PIG Script:
raw_data = LOAD '/input.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (listing_id: chararray, fname: chararray, lname: chararray);
dump raw_data;
STORE raw_data INTO 'hbase://sample_names' USING
org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('info:fname info:lname');

Comment: Did you check `/usr/lib/hbase/hbase-0.94.8/pig_1400548430579.log`?

Comment: I could not find much help from that log... broken the log into 2 comments...
Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 2244: Job failed, hadoop does not return any error message

org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2244: Job failed, hadoop does not return any error message
 at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.executeBatch(GruntParser.java:148)
 at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:202)

Comment: at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:173)
 at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:84)
 at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:607)
 at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:156)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)

Comment: Can you check the `job_201405201031_0005`'s status in the JobTracker web ui?

Comment: Yes, I am able to see...
Failure Info:JobCleanup Task Failure, Task: task_201405201031_0005_m_000001

Comment: Maybe your hbase version is incompatible. Your HBase cluster version is `0.90.1-cdh3u0`, but looks you want to use `0.94.8` in Pig.

Comment: does it work if you change the output to pig storage?

Comment: I tried hbase-0.90.1-cdh3u0.jar, but no luck.. now I removed it... nwo my hbase version is 94.8 kandabap@prakashl:/usr/lib/hbase/hbase-0.94.8$ hbase version 14/05/22 09:24:59 INFO util.VersionInfo: HBase 0.94.8 14/05/22 09:24:59 INFO util.VersionInfo: Subversion svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hbase/branches/0.94 -r 1485407 14/05/22 09:24:59 INFO util.VersionInfo: Compiled by ec2-user on Wed May 22 20:53:13 UTC 2013